# Creating boundary box in Python on randomly generated longitude / latitude points?

Tags: python, software-recommendations, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to create a boundary box to separate a list of randomly generated longitude / latitude points. I would also like to look at the distribution of randomly generated points over time. I wrote a python script that randomly generates 5,000 longitude / latitude points.

How do I write the script and which libraries do I use?

Comment: As it stands you are effectively asking two questions. The first seeks [softwarerecs.se] while the second asks for code writing guidance.

Answer (score 2):

A bounding box is just a coordinate pair, eg. top left and bottom right. It consists of all the coordinate extremes of the contained geometries (points in your case).

It's easiest and fastest to create and track it while generating the main points themselves and you don't really need any extra libraries, since it's just about finding the min and max in two dimensions. Is the new point's X bigger than Xmax? Smaller than Xmin? And the same for Y ...

It only gets complicated if your points are on opposite sides of the date line.